# env: ruby_noexec_wrapper: No such file or directory error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I am getting this error pretty frequently after running this command once....

```
bundle clean --force
```

in my rails project..

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this same thing happened to me, i fixed it according to this comment: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/337#issuecomment-13235367

by running these commands

```
gem install rubygems-bundler
rubygems-bundler-uninstaller
gem uninstall rubygems-bundler
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you were using noexec, which is dead:

https://github.com/joshbuddy/noexec

Check your .gemrc and try running `gem pristine [GEM]` on your gems.

Comment: im running rvm on mac and cannot seem to find noexec in my gemfiles list.. and i dont know where to find the .gemrc you are referring to... can i just run pristine on all the gems in my Gemfile.lock in my rails app? any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like your gem binscripts are running the noexec version of ruby, so you just need to regenerate the binscripts really (which noexec usually does for you). RubyGems doesn't have a built-in way to do this, so try: `require "rubygems/installer"; Gem::Specification.to_a.each { |spec| Gem::Installer.new(File.join(Gem.dir, 'cache', spec.file_name), wrappers: true, force: true, install_dir: File.join(Gem.dir, "gems", spec.full_name)).generate_bin }` (this will fail if you don't still have local caches of your gems).

Comment: (FWIW, rubygems-bundler, the successor to noexec, has similar problems.)

Comment: now it has just gotten worse.. I can no longer run "rails" command since the rails gem is also affected by this :(

Comment: I'm a little hesitant about running your script.. what does it help me do?

Comment: I think the following might have fixed it:

Comment: ```gem install rubygems-bundler```, ```gem regenerate_binstubs```

Comment: The script I added above basically does `regenerate_binstubs`, but in a way that doesn't require rubygems-bundler to be installed at all, ever. Running it again with the gem installed will just cement that you need it installed.

Comment: `gem pristine --all` also works in recent versions of rubygems.