# Getting "sudo: sass: command not found" error when using the sass --watch command in the /var/www directory

Tags: ruby, sass

I'm trying to get SASS to watch an SCSS file for changes. When I run the watch command in any desktop folder, it works e.g. `sass --watch Documents/test.scss:Documents/test.css`.

But when I run it in the /var/www directory, it fails. For example, running `sass --watch /var/www/scss/test.scss:/var/www/css/test.css"` results in the following error: `Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /var/www/css/test.css`. That is likely because the /var/www directory is owned by Apache.

I tried using `sudo sass --watch /var/www/test.scss:/var/www/test.css` command to run the command as root, but that gives me the follow error: `sudo: sass: command not found`.

I'm running this on Ubuntu 12.10 with Ruby 1.9.3. I'm fairly new to both.

Answer (score 2):

Your `sass` binary must be in a location not in root's `$PATH`.  Find where it's located, as your own user:

```
which sass
```

Then use that full path to the `sass` binary in your `sudo` command.

Comment: I tried what you suggested with the following command `sudo /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/sass --watch /var/www/test.scss:/var/www/test.css`, but that gave me the following error: `/usr/bin/env: ruby_noexec_wrapper: No such file or directory`. 

I looked through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127603/usr-bin-env-ruby-noexec-wrapper-fails-with-no-file-or-directory), but that didn't really help. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Then it seems your `sass` command behaviour is tied to your user.  I suggest you add yourself to apache's group, so that you can write to its directories.  Make sure the /var/www directory is apache group-writable (and it would be good as well to setgid that directory; would automagically set your files created on your user behalf to the apache group).

Answer (score 2):

You probably installed `rvm` as an user. If you run a command with `sudo`, you are running it as the user root, where `rvm` and the whole ruby environment is not installed.

*To solve this problem,* you can use **`rvmsudo`** (see http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyversionmanager/qt/Rvm-And-Sudo.htm)