# How to make upstart work gracefully with RVM?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm, thin, upstart

I have a simple Thin webserver I want to start with Upstart. However, upstart needs to be run with sudo which can't see all the RVM gems like Thin. rvmsudo hasn't helped me either. What's the solution for upstart to see your RVM gems?

Comment: RVM is really more for personal use.  For a system service, I would just install the version of Ruby you want (someplace that doesn't conflict with the system version, like /usr/local/)  and use Bundler in deployment mode to get the gemset.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks, I wasn't aware of deployment mode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230404/rvm-and-thin-root-vs-local-user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RVM is really more for personal use. For a system service, I would just install the version of Ruby you want (someplace that doesn't conflict with the system version, like /usr/local/) and use Bundler in deployment mode to get the gemset.

Comment: Why should RVM differentiate between personal and production use? System ruby is normally broken and/or outdated - And I almost never have a smooth setup with it.

Comment: @TJBiddle RVM builds ruby meaning your production build time just increased, not to mention now you have build tools on your production servers, which is usually frowned upon for security reasons.  Having  static binary with your specific ruby version will be faster and more consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a gemset and defaulting to a particular gemset for your project?

1. Default to a Ruby: `rvm use 1.9.3`
2. Create a Gemset Manually (One time): `rvm gemset create
   project-name`
3. Switch to this Gemset: `rvm gemset use project-name`

See if this works, you might be able to later on add this to your `.rvmrc` file for automatic context switching. But give it a shot first and see if this works.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem remains the same -- upstart needs sudo permissions to run & therefore the home directory changes affecting rvm.