# How to start Thin server automatically when System Re boots

Tags: ruby-on-rails, system-administration

How to start thin Server automatically when Server Reboots.

I have a Rails 3 project which uses Thin Server.I can manually control the thin Server from terminal.Is it possible to start thin server as background process when system reboots.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which OS is installed on your server?

Comment: And which init daemon is installed? Upstart, Systemd, System V, ... ?

Comment: Windows Server 2008. Currently no init daemon is installed.Rails Application is now in Server Machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scheduled Tasks. There's a specific trigger option for starting a task when the computer starts.

To start the process in background mode you can use the `-d` option of the `rails` command.

Comment: when i tried to start server like this :  rails s -d    , i am getting an error,  ->  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/core_
ext/process/daemon.rb:3:in `fork': fork() function is unimplemented on this mach
ine (NotImplementedError)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to do this:

`sudo thin install` #to create init.d entry for thin

`sudo /usr/sbin/update-rc.d -f thin defaults` # to setup it

`sudo thin config -C /etc/thin/<appname>.yml -c /var/rails/<appdir> --servers 4 -e production` # to generate congig file for it. If you already got config file, you can just copy it to /etc/thin/ instead of creating.

If you use rvm on your server - browse this: [RVM and thin, root vs. local user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230404/rvm-and-thin-root-vs-local-user).

You can also take a look at: https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/runit